# Why can't I initiate full screen in Lightweight Java Game Library?

Tags: java, lwjgl

I want to enable full screen in ***Lightweight Java Game Library (lwjgl)***. I've got a display mode that is supported for full screen but still it doesn't change to full screen for some reason:

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        Alpha_Core engine = new Alpha_Core();
        setDisplayMode(1280,720, "FullScreenMode"); 
        engine.Init_Program_Loop();
    }

    public static void setDisplayMode(int width, int height, String title)
    {       
        Display.setTitle(title);
        try 
        {
//          DisplayMode[] modes = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();
//          
//          for (int i=0;i<modes.length;i++) {
//              DisplayMode current = modes[i];
//              System.out.println(current.getWidth() + "x" + current.getHeight() + "x" +
//                                  current.getBitsPerPixel() + " " + current.getFrequency() + "Hz");
//          }

            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
            Display.setFullscreen(true);
            Display.create();
            Keyboard.create();
            Mouse.create();
        } 
        catch (LWJGLException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

What am I missing, has it something to do with BitsPerPixel?

Comment: "I have a display mode that is supported for full screen". How? Why? How do you know? You've got nothing there to indicate it supports full screen.

Comment: 1280,720 is supported according to the list DisplayMode current = modes[i]; anyways I know now how to do it, doesn't help me though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
DisplayMode displayMode = null;
        DisplayMode[] modes = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();

         for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++)
         {
             if (modes[i].isFullscreenCapable())
               {
                    displayMode = modes[i];
               }
         }
```

Replace

```
Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(width, height));
```

With

```
Display.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
```

Or, to show you the full code,

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{   
    Alpha_Core engine = new Alpha_Core();
    setDisplayMode(1280,720, "FullScreenMode"); 
    engine.Init_Program_Loop();
}

public static void setDisplayMode(int width, int height, String title)
{       
    Display.setTitle(title);
    DisplayMode displayMode = null;
        DisplayMode[] modes = Display.getAvailableDisplayModes();
         for (int i = 0; i < modes.length; i++)
         {
             if (modes[i].isFullscreenCapable())
               {
                    displayMode = modes[i];
               }
         }
        Display.setDisplayMode(displayMode);
        Display.setFullscreen(true);
        Display.create();
        Keyboard.create();
        Mouse.create();
    } 
    catch (LWJGLException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to adjust how you create/render your scene. Since I have absolutely no idea how to do it (there are literally thousands of different ways, and most people use shaders), it will be hard to help you there. :/